# Spring Data Solr + HATEOAS

Tags: spring-hateoas, spring-data-solr

playing with spring data solr here... I am able to return a page of results in HATEOAS format which is fine i.e.

```
@RequestMapping("/findAllPaged")
HttpEntity<PagedResources<Module>> findAllPaged(Pageable pageable, PagedResourcesAssembler assembler) {

    Page<Module> page = moduleRepository.findAll(pageable)
    return new ResponseEntity<>(assembler.toResource(page), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

but how can I have a method return one entity in the correct HATEOAS format

I currently do the following which gives me basic json serialization, but unsure how to get HATEOAS:

```
@RequestMapping("/module/{id}")
Module module(@PathVariable String id) {
    moduleRepository.findOne(id)
}
```

also how would I return a List in HATEOAS form?

```
@RequestMapping("/findAll")
List<Module> findAll() {
    moduleRepository.findAll().content
}
```

Comment: `Resource<Module>`

Comment: so I modified it like so:       @RequestMapping("/module/{id}")
    Resource<Module> module(@PathVariable String id) {
        new Resource<>(moduleRepository.findOne(id))
    }  but it just gives me basic json:  {
  "name" : "name1",
  "description" : "description1"
}.. shouldn't it have some more fields like _self etc ?

Comment: If you want links you have to add them. Spring doesn't know which links you want to have. You can take a look at Spring Data REST. That framework handles everything automatically and you don't even need to write controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found that if I annotate my repository like so with RepositoryRestResource, then I automatically get rest hateaos services exposed for me

```
@RepositoryRestResource
interface ModuleRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Module, String>{

    /**
     * Does exact (equals) query
     * @param name
     * @param description
     * @param pageable
     * @return
     */
     Page<Module> findByNameOrDescription(@Param(value = "name")@Boost(2.0F) String name, @Param(value = "description") String description, Pageable pageable);

/**
 * Does like query and ignores case
 * @param name
 * @param description
 * @param pageable
 * @return
 */
Page<Module> findByNameContainingOrDescriptionContainingAllIgnoreCase(@Param(value = "name")String name, @Param(value = "description") String description, Pageable pageable);

/**
 * Custom query example
 * @param name
 * @param pageable
 * @return
 */
@Query(value =  "name:*?0*")
Page<Module> myCustomQuery(@Param(value = "name")String name,Pageable pageable);

@Query(value =  "name:*?0* OR description:*?0* ")
Page<Module> myOtherCustomQuery(@Param(value = "name")String name,Pageable pageable);

Page<Module> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(@Param(value = "name")String name, Pageable pageable);



}
```

e.g.

http://localhost:8080/modules/    all docs

http://localhost:8080/modules/1    one doc

http://localhost:8080/modules?page=0&size=4&sort=name,desc   paged results
http://localhost:8080/modules/search/findByNameOrDescription?name=name1&description=description2&page=0&size=10
http://localhost:8080/modules/search/findByNameContainingOrDescriptionContainingAllIgnoreCase?name=mAt&description=sCi&page=0&size=10